# Delete 1st Object From List C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to remove an object from a list of objects but setting the variable object to null isn't destroying it, it's still appearing in the list.

I am sure it's not the best way but I thought it would work, any pointers would be very helpful, thanks.

**Code:**

```
public ActionResult RemoveExisting()
        {
            pa newpa = (pa)Session["pa_Session"];
            if (Session["pa_Session"] != null)
            {
                var todel = newpa.ExistingPas.FirstOrDefault();
                todel = null;
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Comment: `newpa.ExistingPas.RemoveAt(0)` if your list is not empty

Comment: Use List.Remove method? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: if there is not element at 0, it throws Exception : - Index was out of range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use remove for this

```
  var todel = newpa.ExistingPas.FirstOrDefault();
  newpa.ExistingPas.Remove(todel);
  //than add list back to session object if you want updated list
```

Comment: Or alternative way - newpa.ExistingPas.RemoveAt(0);  if colleciton is not empty

Comment: Brilliant stuff, thanks for that! @PawelMaga I tried that but it didn't like it, Pranay's works beautifully. Will accept when it allows.

Comment: Your code need to check whether todel is null or not, before removing it, since default value can be null

Comment: Todel won't be null as I have already checked if the session is null. Surely that is check enough?

Comment: Pawel's code will be a cleaner implementation, it should certainly remove the element at the 0th index if it exist

Comment: Yeah, @PranayRana method is better if you want remove specific object. If you want remove first object like you said you should remove by index.

Comment: @SelrekJohn that check just guarantee that newpa will not be null, it doesn't say anything for ExistingPa and it's first element

Comment: I see no reason to extract the value from the list and then remove it, if the value is not used for anything else. I believe using `RemoveAt()` is a better solution in this specific case.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a [`List`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) you can simply use it's [`RemoveAt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp) method:

```
 if(newpa.ExistingPas.Count>0) 
 {
     newpa.ExistingPas.RemoveAt(0);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The mistake in your code is that you first point a variable to the item you want to delete and then set that variable to null.

That does not change the item and does not change the list, the code only manipulates a variable that is never used.

Use Remove or RemoveAt to change the list.

Comment: Also making null doesn't means removal, it still exist as a valid value

Answer (score 0):

If you frequently need to remove items from the beginning of your `List`, you could user the `Queue` collection type instead and `Dequeue()` items.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx